# Determining OpenID returnURL automatically

Tags: passport.js, google-openid

I'm using passport.js to implement Google OpenID authentication for my webapp. However, I'm not sure what's the best way to specify the returnURL.

Right now I set my server hostname in a config file, like this

```
server.host = 'http://foo.bar.com:5990'
```

But hardcoding the server URL there seems silly to me.

Is there any way to tell passport.js or Google OpenID auth to return to the same domain it started from?

Comment: Got the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, turns out I can just use a relative URL in the returnURL and it will work. :-)

Comment: I tried using relative url and it just leads to a google error page. Looks like things have changed over the past year

Comment: @lastoneisbearfood Google OpenID is now deprecated in favour of OAuth anyway methinks.